# Register new event listeners in Polymer 1.0 after initial page load

Tags: dom, polymer-1.0

In my Polymer 1.0 app, I have an on-tap function which dynamically adds another button into the page based on a few parameters in the form. The problem is that after adding the element and its event listener to the page, the new button won't actually fire the on-tap event.

JSFiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/dme6tb7z/

**index.html**

```
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">
<div id="output"></div>
<paper-button id="myButton" on-tap="_addButton">Add Button</paper-button>
</template>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Here is where I create the new button and give it a listener in JS. Is there some kind of extra step I need to take so that Polymer can "see" the new on-tap event listener?

**app.js**

```
app._addButton = function(e) {
  var el = document.createElement('paper-button');
  el.innerHTML = "New Button";
  el.id = "newbutton";
  el.addEventListener('on-tap', '_testEvent');
  this.$.output.appendChild(el);

  // I also tried adding the event listener after appending 
  // the element to the page, like so...

  // this.$.newButton.addEventListener('on-tap', '_testEvent');
};

app._testEvent = function(e) {
  console.log(e);
};
```

**EDIT**

I'm thinking maybe I need to use something like `Polymer.dom(parent).appendChild(node)` to keep the two DOMs in sync. I did this in my app.js like so, but the event still doesn't fire.

**app.js scope**

```
(function(document) {
  'use strict';
  var app = document.querySelector('#app');
  ...
  app._addButton = function(e) {
    var el = document.createElement('paper-button');
    el.innerHTML = "New Button";
    el.id = "newbutton";
    el.addEventListener('on-tap', '_testEvent');
    var parentNode = document.getElementById('output');
    Polymer.dom(parentNode).appendChild(el);
};
  ...
})(document);
```

Surely, there *must* be some way to add event listeners after initial page load? I've done this same thing countless times in other setups, but there's something weird going on with Polymer... I understand there are two DOMs to update, but I'm using the `Polymer.dom` method, so what in the world is preventing this from happening?

**More Info**

I noticed that after appending the new button to the page, I can successfully run this:

`document.getElementById('newbutton').innerHTML = 'Hello World';`

whereas this:

`document.getElementById('newbutton').addEventListener('on-tap', '_testEvent');`

has no effect (and no errors). Isn't that bizarre? Is there some sort of reinvented registration process in Polymer to add event listeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured it out.

First of all, `on-tap` in this context should be `tap`.

Second, the function name from JS should be formatted like this: `this.functionName`, or `app.functionName` if your template has an id of "app" and app is defined as `var app = document.querySelector('#app');`

All together, it looks like this:

```
var newElement = document.getElementById('newbutton');
newElement.addEventListener('tap', this._testEvent );
```

This doesn't work in the JS Fiddle for some reason, but does work in a real Polymer environment.